# How to test a cookie from our company domain with localhost?

Tags: asp.net

I am working on an asp.net intranet, that looks for a cookie from our main domain. The cookies domain value is set to "mydomain.com". Now I can easily access this cookie if I am on the same sub domain (http://test.mydomain.com). However is there a way for me to test this from http://localhost as well?

Comment: Why not simply point your host file for that domain to your machine, and then run the website through IIS? That way, there is no distinction; that domain IS your computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put an entry in your [host file](http://www.ezlan.net/host.html) on your local machine so that requesting your company domain gets sent to a local ip address (like 127.0.0.1). Then, make sure you have a web site setup in IIS that uses that IP and host name.

Comment: Thats awsome. I did not think of this. Thanks a lot.